# Why cv::imread return NULL after include tensorflow's header

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, imread

I am using the tensorflow c++ API in my code. And I found when I load image from files the image is NULL. Then I write a test code to find the reason.

Here is my test code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std;

//#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
//#include "tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h"

int main()
{
    Mat imgtry = imread("lena.jpg");
    printf("%dx%d", imgtry.cols, imgtry.rows );
    return 0;
}
```

When I comment tensorflow's header, the output value is 255x255, but once I uncomment the header, the output value is 0x0. Why ???

The problem seems change slightly after I revised the sequence of link library. At first, I link the `tensorflow_cc` and `tensorflow_frameworok` and then the `opencv`'s libriries. Now, I put the tensorflow's libraries after the opencv and the let corresponding include directory as the same sequence. Then I can read image normally even uncomment the code in the above code area. But new porblem occured.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"

//it's ok.
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h"

using namespace std;    
int main()
{

    cv::Mat img;
    img = cv::imread("lena.jpg");
    if(img.empty() == true) {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "ok!" << endl;

    //uncomment this, the img is always emtpy!!!
//  tensorflow::SessionOptions sessOptions;
//  sessOptions.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(true);
//  auto session = tensorflow::NewSession(sessOptions);
//  if(session == nullptr) {
//      cout << "Could not create Tensorflow session." << endl;
//      exit(1);
//  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't pollute the namespace (i.e. remove `using namespace cv`) and just use `cv::imread()`? (Also will need to use `cv::Mat`)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds No, it’s the same problem.

Comment: It seems like a [known bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14267)

Comment: @Miki 0.0 .... It is!!! Thanks~

Comment: Nice find @Miki.

Comment: @Miki Make that an answer, or at least a community one, that seems pretty useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14267)

---

<sup>Feel free to update this Community Wiki answer with Workaround / Solution / Bug status / Etc...</sup>